# Assigning link, site and global IPv6 address

Tags: ipv6

How can I assign link, site and global IPv6 addresses at a same time using `/etc/network/interfaces` file? I am able to assign any one of them address at a time.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you've got so far, please.

Comment: Actually what do you want? I have just assigned 3 different types of IPv6 address to my device using /etc/network/interfaces file and ping them from different devices and PCs. Here you should make sure that if you want to ping any global unique address, you should have global unique address otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 3):

The link-local address will be assigned automatically. You do not need to configure anything in `/etc/network/interfaces` to make that happen.

"Special" site-local IPv6 addresses are sort of an obsolete concept: an idea that was part of the original IPv6 spec that turned out to have problems and was removed. Today there is a replacement called [Unique Local Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193) but they're not treated specially by the protocol. A ULA address is just another unicast address you can assign to an interface as far as the networking stack is concerned. Is ULA what you mean when you say "site"?

As for assigning multiple IP addresses to an interface, the normal `address`, `netmask` etc... directives only handle a single address. To configure multiple addresses,

- pick one address and configure it normally (using `address` and `netmask`)
- Add all other addresses using custom commands executed when the interface comes up:

  ```
   up ip addr add abcd:defg::whatever/64 dev <interface name>
  ```

Comment: Yes I mean ULA by "site". OK i got it that link local address will be generated automatically. But, if I want to assign ULA and Global unique address or say 2 global unique addresses using /etc/network/interfaces file only. Is there any way? I can not use command suggested by you.

Comment: I am not aware of any way other than what I suggested. Why can you not use that?

Comment: Ok. Thank you ma'm. I am configuring IPv6 in my device so when it gets static IPv6 from user, it will be stored in /etc/network/interfaces file. User can not go to terminal to write this code.

Comment: I understand. I read the manpage again just to confirm; it looks like there is no other way. Perhaps whatever is automatically updating `/etc/network/interfaces` with user-supplied data can be modified to handle adding `up` directives for additional addresses? After all, they go right in the same location in the same file.

Comment: It's done using following lines in /etc/network/interfaces file:
auto eth0:0
 iface eth0:0 inet6 static
        address fec0::1eba:8cff:fee5:c117
        netmask 64